# Adding digit separators to views

Tags: feature-request

In honor of [how to exit vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/2069064) hitting [1 million views](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/?cb=1), I think it's time to point out that this looks ridiculous:

[image]

Can we please add digit separators so that this shows up as `1,000,082` or `1.000.082` as appropriate (or even `1.00M` or `1.05 Jon Skeet`)? It takes quite a bit of effort for those questions with [tons of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git) to actually figure out how many views they have.

Comment: +1 for the red freehand circles.

Comment: I approve of a Jon Skeet-based measuring system.